# Can't start Maven 3.0.5 from installation folder

Tags: windows, maven

I'm using the java version 1.5.0_30, the JAVA_HOME env. variable has been correctly set together with the java bin folder in the 'Path'. I have downloaded Maven 3.0.5 and checked the standard requirements (jdk 1.5 and above). Using the windows command prompt when I went to the **apache-maven-3.0.5\bin** directory I tried to run 'mvn' and 'mvn -version' to see if Maven has been installed correctly or not but I keep receiving :

**'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Please note that I can't update my JDK because I am on a corporate PC (so I can't use more recent maven versions because they don't support the 1.5 java jdk).

Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is mvn actually there?

Comment: Yes I have all the standard files : m2.conf,mvn,mvn.bat,mvnDebug,mvnDebug.bat,mvnyjp

Comment: It's weird because it works with mvn.bat --version

Comment: Can you take a look at your path environment variable? It may contain something that is causing this not to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ED, the path seems fine otherwise I would not be able to access mvn.bat outside the maven bin folder.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to add the `...\apache-3.0.5\bin` folder to your path. Afterwards you need to close and reopen the console.

Furthermore the java itself is not needed being part of the PATH only JAVA_HOME must be set correctly.

You can upgrade until [Maven 3.1.1 which is the last release which supports Java 1.5](http://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html).

Comment: The OP has stated that they can't run mvn from the bin directory, so adding the bin directory to the path seems pointless (unless it actually helps for some odd reason :)

Comment: If you tries to start and the output is the posted error message the OP does not start it from the bin folder.